# Symfony embedded Controller with before Filter

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using Symfony2 and want to retrieve the newest unread messsages in my sidebar. So I used the embedded Controller as in the documentation here:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers

thats all fine and working. The Problem now is that i'm also using a before filter in every controller to check the session and some rights. In this eventlistener i do a redirect to the login page, if the session is not valid.

I know that a redirect is not possible in a embedded Controller and thats why i get an error. So know my question how to handle this. Is there a way to exclude some functions from the before filter?

Or do i have to make a new controller for all the functions i want to use as embedded Content?

Comment: try to apply "before filter" only on master request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your listener you should be able to check if the request is master, as described in the [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/event_listener.html#request-events-checking-types), and if it's not, just don't return a `RedirectResponse`:

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
        return;
    }

    // Your other code here
}
```